# How to update only clicked item at Recyclerview adapter not the last visible one?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344319/why-my-notifyitemchanged-change-the-wrong-item-of-rv) question previously and after some investigation I got to know that my onBindViewHolder updates the wrong item of my list. What does it mean? For example I pressed 0 item of my list and it will update the view of 6-th item. I don't know why does it happen because I thought previously that `notifyItemChanged()` will change clicked item not  the last visible item of my list.My adapter class:

```
open class JobsAdapter(private val jobs: ArrayList<JobModel>, private val ctx: Context, private val click: Click) : RecyclerView.Adapter<JobsAdapter.JobsHolder>() {
    lateinit var view: View


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, p1: Int): JobsHolder {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.job_list_item, viewGroup, false)
        return JobsHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return jobs.size
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: JobsHolder, position: Int) {
        val jobModel = jobs[position]
        holder.tvPosition.text = jobModel.position
        holder.tvAddress.text = jobModel.location
        holder.tvCompany.text = jobModel.company_name

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if (!jobModel.isSeen) {
                    Singleton.clickReq(jobModel.id, ctx)

            }

            holder.itemView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.message_list_item_bg)

            click.sendData(Uri.parse(jobModel.job_link).toString(), holder.adapterPosition, jobModel.position!!)
        }

        holder.ivAddTo.setOnClickListener {
            holder.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.ivAddTo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.added_to_notepad)
            holder.ivAddTo.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.ivAddTo.isClickable = false
            Singleton.jobLstPos = position



                saveToNotepad(jobModel.id)
        }


        if (jobModel.isSeen) {
            holder.itemView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(ctx, R.drawable.message_list_item_bg)
        } else {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fafafa"))
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: JobsHolder, position: Int, payloads: List<Any>) {
        if (payloads.isNotEmpty()) {
            when (payloads[0]) {
                1 -> {
                    holder.ivAddTo.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
        }
    }

    private fun saveToNotepad(id: Int) {
        Singleton.apiService(ctx).saveTo("Bearer " + ctx.getSharedPreferences("appD", 0).getString("access_token", ""), id).enqueue(object : Callback<SaveTo> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<SaveTo>, response: Response<SaveTo>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    notifyItemChanged(view.getTag(R.id.tag_3) as Int, 1)
                } 
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<SaveTo>, t: Throwable) {
            }
        })
    }

    class JobsHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var tvCompany = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_company)!!
        var tvDate = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_date)!!
        var tvPosition = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_job_title)!!
        var tvAddress = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_address)!!
        var ivAddTo = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.add_to_notepad)!!
        var progressBar = itemView.findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBar)
    }
}
```

After clicking add button I send request and if it is successful I would like to stop progress bar, change its visibility and change background of clicked btn. So, why does it happen and how I can solve this problem?

Comment: post your adapter code and list updating code

Comment: rows are recycled in recyclerview, so without proper binding of data with the row, the changed data will reflect on recycled rows too

Comment: @ManojPerumarath, I have updated my question

Comment: @VivekMishra, what did you mean with proper binding data? Can you check my edition of question please?

Comment: by proper binding I mean that if you are changing color based on some condition, then you should also set default color in the else condition

Comment: I have set default background for btn also, I don't understand why I change wrong item :( I would like to update certain view after successful response and it is all :(

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by adding special function for updating view:

```
fun changeView(position: Int, permission: Boolean) {
        notifyItemChanged(position, permission)
    }
```

and then `onBindViewHolder()`:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: JobsHolder, position: Int, payloads: List<Any>) {
        if (payloads.isNotEmpty()) {
            when (payloads[0]) {
                true -> {
                    holder.ivAddTo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.added_to_notepad)
                    holder.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    holder.ivAddTo.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
                false->{
                    holder.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
                    holder.ivAddTo.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }
        } else {
            super.onBindViewHolder(holder, position, payloads)
        }
    }
```

maybe it will help smb else.